# How to replace values in a Vector

Tags: r

```
data1<-data.frame(x1=c("a","b"),x2=c("b","b"),x3=c("c","b"),x4=c("d","b"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
aaa<-as.character(data1[1,])
aaa
```

I want to replace a with \M, b with \N, others with \O in aaa vector. How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Why is `data1` even in this question? And you want to replace the single character "b" with the two characters "\" and "M"?

Comment: vector aaa was generated from dataframe data1. I want to replace the single character "a" with the two characters "\" and "M",the single character "b" with the two characters "\" and "N",others with the two characters "\" and "O".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy answer would be:

```
aaa[aaa!="a"&aaa!="b"]<-"\\O"
aaa[aaa=="a"]<-"\\M"
aaa[aaa=="b"]<-"\\N"
```

But your problem here seems that you are trying to define unrecognized symbols such as \M.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lookup vector to automate this:

```
vec <- setNames(c("\\M","\\N"),c("a","b"))
ifelse(aaa %in% names(vec),vec[as.character(aaa)],"\\O")

#[1] "\\M" "\\N" "\\O" "\\O"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another overkill approach:

```
library(qdapTools)
lookup(aaa, list(`\\M`="a", `\\N` ="b"), missing = "\\O")

## [1] "\\M" "\\N" "\\O" "\\O"
```